# Does a Divine Soul Sorcerer have access to the additional cleric spells in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Additional Cleric Spells

> 1st-level cleric feature
>
> The spells in the following list expand the cleric spell list in the
> Player’s Handbook. The list is organized by spell level, not character
> level.

Divine Magic

> When your Spellcasting feature lets you learn or replace a sorcerer cantrip or a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, you can choose the new spell from the cleric spell list or the sorcerer spell list. You must otherwise obey all the restrictions for selecting the spell, and it becomes a sorcerer spell for you.

**Do the additional spells count as being on the Cleric's spell list for the purposes of Divine Magic as long as both supplements are agreed to be used?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes.

Divine Magic doesn’t restrict the sorcerer to the cleric spell list in the *Player’s Handbook*, it just says that they can use the cleric spell list. *Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything* is explicitly adding to that list—so divine soul sorcerers benefit just the same as clerics do.

Answer (score 10):

#### Update: As of early 2021, Wizards of the Coast has removed the PHB+1 rule from Adventurer’s League, meaning that Divine Soul Sorcerers can now benefit from the expanded Cleric spell list in Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything.

The blog post announcing this change can be found here: https://yawningportal.dnd.wizards.com/blog/saying-goodbye-to-the-ph1-rule/

---

#### Yes, but not in Adventurer’s League.

The Adventurer's League is the official play venue for Dungeons and Dragons 5e run by Wizards of the Coast. In Adventurer’s League play, you’re limited to using the rules in the Player’s Handbook plus one other book, aside from equipment and a few specific rules mentioned in the AL player guide. That book could be Xanathar’s Guide to Everything or Tasha’s Cauldron of Everything, but you can’t use both at the same time, like using a subclass from one book and spells from another.

It’s possible that as time goes on and more books are released, this rule might be loosened or removed, but for now, it remains in force.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my answer, I'd appreciate an explanation of why.

Comment: I haven’t voted either way, but the question never said anything about Adventurer’s League. Personally, I don’t see anything wrong with the added information so long as it’s accurate. Others, it would seem, see this as not answering the question, since the question didn’t ask about Adventurer’s League. And they have a point—answers should be complete answers. You should answer the question asked first, and then add the extra information. Even if it’s just “Yes” and a link to my answer for details, followed by what you currently have, you may see better votes. Maybe; I’m just guessing.

Comment: (I haven’t—and won’t—vote on this because I don’t know anything about the Adventurer’s League and don’t care to know anything about it, so I can’t judge if this information is accurate or not.)

Comment: I think this answer is good because it prevents people from making silly mistakes.

Comment: Haven't downvoted either, but a "Yes BUT not in AL" would've been a way better answer.